# Swift2: can extensions make public implementations that manipulate private variables?

Tags: protocols, swift2, private

I want to create a struct that stores variables that can't be seen directly but can be modified by public functions.

As much as possible, I want to define all this using protocols and extensions with default implementations.

Here's my first try (this can be pasted directly into a Playground):

```
import Foundation

private protocol VariablesIWantToHide {
  var numGerbils: Int { get set }
  var numHamsters: Int { get set }
}

protocol MethodsIWantToAccess {
  mutating func setGerbilCount(amount: Int)
  mutating func setHamsterCount(amount:Int)
}

protocol MultiAccess: VariablesIWantToHide, MethodsIWantToAccess {}

extension MultiAccess {
  mutating func setGerbilCount(amount: Int) {
    numGerbils = amount
  }
  mutating func setHamsterCount(amount: Int) {
    numHamsters = amount
  }
}

struct MultiAccessStruct: MultiAccess {
  var numGerbils: Int = 0
  var numHamsters: Int = 0
}
```

This generates the error message `error: protocol must be declared private because it refines a private protocol`.

The overall goal is the `extension MultiAccess` part, where I define default public functions that manipulate private variables. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It generates an error message as protocol MultiAccess has an access control of internal since no explicit access control modifier is specified .

Since it refines protocol VariablesIWantToHide which is private , MultiAccess should also be private as per the access control guiding principle which is

"**No entity can be defined in terms of another entity that has a lower (more restrictive) access level**"

The goal to access private internal variables using public functions cannot be achieved using extensions with default implementation as an extensions access level can always be less than or equal to the class/protocol that it is extending.